# Introduction to perl input and output

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script which I am trying to understand. I am quoting first few lines of the script (abc.pl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DateTime;
use File::Temp;
use Math::Complex;
use Getopt::Long;
use TauP::Time;
use Seed::Response;
use lib '/usr/lib/perl5';
use Seismogram::SAC;

my(@input,$output);
GetOptions('input=s{,}' => \@input, 'output=s' => \$output);

open my $out_fp,">$output";
foreach my $file (<@input>)
{
 my $phase = 'S';
 if ( $file =~ /BHZ/ ) { $phase = 'P';}
 my $decData = File::Temp->new();
 decimateData($file,$decData);
 my($sac) = readSAC($decData);
 my($resp) = readResponse($sac);
}
```

I have a few files which I have listed in "list".
Can anyone please let me understand how should I input "list" and output filenames to the perl script.

Comment: Are you asking for a line-by-line explanation of the script?

Comment: No, just let me understand this line my (@input, $output). suppose my input file is list and output file is out_list. How should I input these? And in the next line what is this form input=s{,} indicating?

Comment: `my(@input,$output)` is just declaring variables.  They are assigned by GetOptions according to command line flags that you pass when the script is invoked.  `abc.pl --input foo --input bar --output baz` will make the array `@input` have the 2 entries 'foo' and 'bar' and `$output` will be 'baz'.  Assuming you fix the shebang so that the script even runs, that is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This is what I was looking for. I have corrected the hash bang line and the script is running ok.

Comment: You would do better to read the documentation for [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) than to ask us to repeat parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
my(@input,$output);
```

This line declares variables used on next line (`@input` is an array of input files, `$output` is scalar for output filename)

```
GetOptions('input=s{,}' => \@input, 'output=s' => \$output);
```

`GetOptions` is a function from module `Getopt::Long` and this line parses commandline options and fills previously declared variables. You should read [module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long)

Comment: Can you please tell me how should I supply the input to the perl script? perl abc.pl < list out_list? Is this the correct way.

Comment: I can help you, but you must show your efforts too. If you can't google for Perl tutorial I suggest to start with https://perlmaven.com/perl-tutorial

Comment: I have been google-ing but was not able to find the exact way to input and output. This link you have given is brilliant. Thanks for the suggestion.